# get rotation between two frames

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,everyone,

I have two frames, one is global frame("`map`"), another is local frame ("`laser`"). And I have the transform between them.

I want to publish a Navigation Goal, and the Goal is obtaining from the laserscan. The Goal's position is obtaining from a laserscan range `float ra = scan_msg->ranges[t]` ,and the Goal's orientation is get from a angle `float angle = scan_msg->angle_min +t * scan_msg->angle_increment`,here the `t` is a constant(specified).

Thank you in advance!

**edit 11-03**

```
    tf::StampedTransform transform;
    geometry_msgs::PoseStamped new_goal;
     geometry_msgs::PointStamped position_in, position_out;
    int id = 50;
        try
        {
            listener->waitForTransform("/map", "/laser", scan_msg->header.stamp, ros::Duration(10.0));
            listener->lookupTransform("/map", "/laser",  scan_msg->header.stamp, transform);
        }
        catch (tf::TransformException& ex)
        {
            ROS_ERROR("Received an exception trying to transform a point from \"laser\" to \"map\": %s", ex.what());
        }

        float angle = scan_msg->angle_min + id * scan_msg->angle_increment;
        pt.x = ra * cos(angle);
        pt.y = ra * sin(angle);

        position_in.header = scan_msg->header;
        position_in.point.x = pt.x;
        position_in.point.y = pt.y;
        listener->transformPoint("map", position_in, position_out);


        // header
        new_goal.header.frame_id = "map";
        new_goal.header.stamp = ros::Time::now();
        // position
        new_goal.pose.position.x = position_out.point.x;
        new_goal.pose.position.y = position_out.point.y;
        new_goal.pose.position.z = 0.0;

        tf::Quaternion q = transform.getRotation();
        double yaw = tf::getYaw(q);
        double angle_goal = yaw + angle_orientation;
        
        geometry_msgs::Quaternion goal_quat = tf::createQuaternionMsgFromYaw(angle_goal);
        new_goal.pose.orientation = goal_quat;
        p_pub.publish(new_goal);
```

I solve the problem in two steps.

First, transform the point position from /laser to /map, as `listener->transformPoint("map", position_in, position_out);`

Second, calculate the Yaw from /laser to /map as `double angle_goal = yaw + angle_orientation;`

I need to do some test and verify.

If somebody have good Suggestions, please let me know.

Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/246991/get-rotation-between-two-frames/) by [chengwei](https://answers.ros.org/users/27203/chengwei/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2016-11-01

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [JoshMarino](https://answers.ros.org/users/27952/joshmarino/) on 2016-11-01**:
If you have the transformation matrix, the rotation matrix is the first 3x3 elements. From the rotation matrix, you can convert it to quaternion (or Euler angles).

[Link](https://en.m.wikibooks.org/wiki/Robotics_Kinematics_and_Dynamics/Description_of_Position_and_Orientation)

**Comment by [chengwei](https://answers.ros.org/users/27203/chengwei/) on 2016-11-01**:
I want to publish a goal position to the robot，and I want get the position from a laserscan as fellows.

```
float ra = scan_msg->ranges[t];
float angle = scan_msg->angle_min + i * scan_msg->angle_increment;
```

I could transform coordinate from "base_link" to "map" , how to transform the angle?

**Comment by [chengwei](https://answers.ros.org/users/27203/chengwei/) on 2016-11-02**:
Hi,JoshMarino,

Sorry for my poor English,

I want to publish a Navigation Goal,now I want to transform a Orientation from a local frame(`laser`) to a global frame (`map`), and I get the Orientation as a angle `angle = scan_msg->angle_min + t * scan_msg->angle_increment`, any suggest is acceptable!

**Comment by [JoshMarino](https://answers.ros.org/users/27952/joshmarino/) on 2016-11-02**:
[Line 24](http://wiki.ros.org/tf/Tutorials/Writing%20a%20tf%20listener%20%28Python%29) will get transformation (translation and rotation) between two frames. [Here](https://github.com/ros/geometry/blob/hydro-devel/tf/src/tf/transformations.py) can convert rotation matrix to angles or quaternion.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-11-03**:
Could you please post your last edit as an *answer*, and then accept your own answer? That shows much more clearly that your question was answered than if you close it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[tf::Transform](http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/tf/html/c++/classtf_1_1Transform.html) has methods for obtaining rotations like [getRotation()](http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/tf/html/c++/classtf_1_1Transform.html#a76da1e3b138a70fbf97dc26039ed031c).

Though, you can multiply `Transform`s directly to have angular and linear transformations. No need to separate them.

**Edit**:

I'm not sure if I get you correct but you can transform your laser scan to map using **TF** like this;

```
tf::StampedTransform transform;
ros::Time t = ros::Time(0);
tf_->waitForTransform("map", "laser", t, ros::Duration(1.0));
tf_->lookupTransform("map", "laser", t, transform);
```

then, you can get x, y and theta like;

```
double x = transform.getOrigin().getX();
double y = transform.getOrigin().getY();
double th = tf::getYaw(transform.getRotation());
```

Is this what you ask for?

---

Originally posted by [Akif](https://answers.ros.org/users/23527/akif/) with karma: 3561 on 2016-11-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [chengwei](https://answers.ros.org/users/27203/chengwei/) on 2016-11-02**:
Hi,Akif,
I'm sorry for my poor English.
I want to publish a Navigation Goal, and the Goal's position is obtaining from a laserscan range `float ra = scan_msg->ranges[t]` ,and the Goal's orientation is get from a angle `float angle = scan_msg->angle_min + t * scan_msg->angle_increment`，

**Comment by [artemiialessandrini](https://answers.ros.org/users/36583/artemiialessandrini/) on 2019-11-27**:
How does tf_ declared?

**Comment by [ParkerRobert](https://answers.ros.org/users/56923/parkerrobert/) on 2021-04-02**:
First include the correct header:

```
#include <tf/transform_listener.h>
```

Followed by defining the following:

```
tf::TransformListener *tf_ = new tf::TransformListener;
tf_->waitForTransform("map", "laser", t, ros::Duration(1.0));
tf_->lookupTransform("map", "laser", t, transform);
```

For more information, you can refer to: http://wiki.ros.org/tf/Tutorials/Writing%20a%20tf%20listener%20%28C%2B%2B%29